# Hints and tips for a Windows service I am creating in C# and Quartz.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, quartz.net

I have a project ongoing at the moment which is create a Windows Service that essentially moves files around multiple paths. A job may be to, every 60 seconds, get all files matching a regular expression from an FTP server and transfer them to a Network Path, and so on. These jobs are stored in an SQL database.

Currently, the service takes the form of a console application, for ease of development. Jobs are added using an ASP.NET page, and can be editted using another ASP.NET page.

I have some issues though, some relating to Quartz.NET and some general issues.

## Quartz.NET:

1: This is the biggest issue I have. Seeing as I'm developing the application as a console application for the time being, I'm having to create a new Quartz.NET scheduler on all my files/pages. This is causing multiple confusing errors, but I just don't know how to institate the scheduler in one global file, and access these in my ASP.NET pages (so I can get details into a grid view to edit, for example)

2: My manager would suggested I could look into having multiple 'configurations' inside Quartz.NET. By this, I mean that at any given time, an administrator can change the applications configuration so that only specifically chosen applications run. What'd be the easiest way of doing this in Quartz.NET?

## General:

1: One thing that that's crucial in this application is assurance that the file has been moved and it's actually on the target path (after the move the original file is deleted, so it would be disastrous if the file is deleted when it hasn't actually been copied!). I also need to make sure that the files contents match on the initial path, and the target path to give peace of mind that what has been copied is right. I'm currently doing this by MD5 hashing the initial file, copying the file, and before deleting it make sure that the file exists on the server. Then I hash the file on the server and make sure the hashes match up. Is there a simpler way of doing this? I'm concerned that the hashing may put strain on the system.

2: This relates to the above question, but isn't *as important* as not even my manager has any idea how I'd do this, but I'd love to implement this. An issue would arise if a job is executed when a file is being written to, which may be that a half written file will be transferred, thus making it totally useless, and it would also be bad as the the initial file would be destroyed while it's being written to! Is there a way of checking of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've discovered, running the Quartz scheduler inside an ASP.NET presents many problems.  Check out Marko Lahma's response to your question about running the scheduler inside of an ASP.NET web app:

[Quartz.Net scheduler works locally but not on remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763072/quartz-net-scheduler-works-locally-but-not-on-remote-host)

As far as preventing race conditions between your jobs (eg. trying to delete a file that hasn't actually been copied to the file system yet), what you need to implement is some sort of job-chaining:

http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/faq.html#howtochainjobs

In the past I've used the TriggerListeners and JobListeners to do something similar to what you need.  Basically, you register event listeners that wait to execute certain jobs until after another job is completed.  It's important that you test out those listeners, and understand what's happening when those events are fired.  You can easily find yourself implementing a solution that seems to work fine in development (false positive) and then fails to work in production, without understanding how and when the scheduler does certain things with regards to asynchronous job execution.

Good luck!  Schedulers are fun!