# trigger not fire in Quartz.net web site

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, quartz.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Quartz.Net scheduler works locally but not on remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763072/quartz-net-scheduler-works-locally-but-not-on-remote-host)

when i use this code:

job code:

```
Public Class ImportJob
Implements IJob
Public Sub Execute(context As IJobExecutionContext) Implements IJob.Execute
    '''some code
End Sub
End Class
```

trigger code:

```
Public Class ScheduleManager
Public Shared Property Scheduler As IScheduler
  Public Sub RunTrigger()
    Dim startTime As DateTimeOffset
        startTime = DateBuilder.DateOf(20, 0, 0)

    Dim scheduler = GetScheduler
    Dim job As IJobDetail = JobBuilder.Create(Of ImportJob)().WithIdentity("jobname").Build()
    Dim trigger As ITrigger
        trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create().ForJob(job).WithIdentity("som Name").WithDescription("some Desc").StartAt(startTime).WithSimpleSchedule(Function(x) x.WithIntervalInHours(24).RepeatForever).Build()

    scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger)
    scheduler.Start()
End Sub
Public ReadOnly Property GetScheduler As IScheduler
    Get
        If Scheduler Is Nothing Then
            Scheduler = New StdSchedulerFactory().GetScheduler()
        End If
        Return Scheduler
    End Get
End Property

End Class
```

and in global:

```
 Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Code that runs on application startup
    Dim schde As New ScheduleManager
    schde.RunTrigger()
End Sub
```

i use this trigger and job for scheduling,when i use that code trigger must be fire in 20:00,but trigger not fire?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a duplicate of [Quartz.Net scheduler works locally but not on remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763072/quartz-net-scheduler-works-locally-but-not-on-remote-host) . So please use a global reference to your scheduler factory and be aware of application pool recycles.

Comment: Any idea for [Cannot keep alive Web Application on IIS after Recycling or Restarting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33593602/cannot-keep-alive-web-application-on-iis-after-recycling-or-restarting). pls?